# BigQuery: Set expirationTime on Snapshot

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a BigQuery snapshot of a table with an expiration date 60 minutes in the future.
It looks like I can't define a expiration time when creating the snapshot, as [CopyJobConfig](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/3.0.1/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.CopyJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.CopyJobConfig) doesn't support it.
So I create the snapshot first, then try to update it's metadata.

Using the following code

```
expDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
dstTable = client.get_table(f"{project}.{dataset}.{tblName}")
dstTable.expires = expDate
client.update_table(dstTable, ['expires'])
```

doesn't work as I get:
`google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PATCH ... : Only table expirationTime, description, friendlyName and labels can be updated for a snapshot.`

OK, so it looks like I need to use expirationTime for snapshots, so I tried:

```
expDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
dstTable = client.get_table(f"{project}.{dataset}.{tblName}")
dstTable.expirationTime= expDate
client.update_table(dstTable, ['expirationTime'])
```

Which kind of works, but the timestamp is set 6 months into the future, not 1 hour as I've specified:
[image: wrong expiration date]

There is no default expiration set on the dataset, so I don't understand where the 6 months are coming from.
How can I properly set a snapshot's expiration time?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Snapshot expiration time can be set in BigQuery by using following four ways only :

- BigQuery Console
- SQL
- bq tool
- API

If the expiration time is not set then the snapshot will automatically set the expiration time  after 6 months. For your requirement you can choose any one of the above options to set snapshot expiration time. For more information you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-create#create_a_table_snapshot_with_an_expiration). Snapshots metadata can be [updated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-update#update_a_table_snapshots_metadata).  You can keep track on this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/228878725) for details on failing to update metadata of table snapshots.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm using Python (google-cloud-bigquery) and was under the impression, that it uses the API you mention. So I thought there has to be a way to set the expiration date of a snapshot. Is that a limitation of the googel-cloud-bigquery then? Also: Why does it set a expiration time after 6 months for a snapshot, even if there is no expiration default set on the dataset?

Comment: @pgruetter, You can set the snapshot expiration time by using API or Cloud Console UI. If the default expiration time for snapshot is not set then BigQuery will automatically set it to 6 months.